# How can I generate a tensor of indices for another tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have some multidimensional tensor `t`. For example:

```
tensor([[0., 1., 2.],
        [3., 4., 5.]])
```

I would like to generate another tensor `idx`, which contains the indices of `t`:

```
tensor([[[0, 0],
         [0, 1],
         [0, 2]],

        [[1, 0],
         [1, 1],
         [1, 2]]])
```

More generally: given tensor `t`, of shape `(d0, d1, ..., dn)`, tensor `idx` should be of shape `(d0, d1, ..., dn, n)`

I have a way of generating this procedurally, but it's not pretty:

```
idx = torch.zeros(*t.shape, t.ndim, dtype=torch.long)
for d in range(t.ndim):
    idx_d = torch.arange(t.shape[d])
    shape_d = [-1 if i==d else 1 for i in range(t.ndim)]
    idx_d = idx_d.view(shape_d)
    idx_d = idx_d.expand(t.shape)
    idx[..., d] = idx_d
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `torch.cartesian_prod(*(torch.arange(i) for i in t.shape)).reshape(*t.shape, t.ndim)`, but it's not nice either.